# How make y axis corresponding to the values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have only 3 numbers at y axis: 1, 1.7, 2.4

```
  dt <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1.7, 2.4), b = letters[1:3])
  ggplot(dt, aes(b,a, fill = a)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I know I can adjust it manually, but is there a simple way to make ggplot do it automatic?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale_y_continuous()` and set brakes according to your data:

```
dt <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1.7, 2.4), b = letters[1:3])
ggplot(dt, aes(b,a, fill = a)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = dt$a)
```

If this *automatic* enough.

[image]

Comment: Then I get percentage in another data set :O

Comment: @WW what exactly do you mean?

Comment: In my real dataset I get y axis with values: 25% and 75% instead of values like: 1400, 2874.5, 6788 . These values are computed as quantile25, median and quantile75

Comment: OK, this is becuz the values has names. `names(values) <- NULL` fixed it :)